# Laravel two middlewares same query

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.6

I have two route groups A and B. I have two middlewares that check something like.
Middleware1: `(if something in my database has status == 0)  { return $next($request);} else { redirect to route X }`

Middleware2: `(if something in my database has status != 0)  { return $next($request);} else { redirect to route X }`

I have route X with SomeController@action something like:
`(if something in my database has status == 0) { redirect to a route in route group A) ELSE { redirect to a route in route group B)`

I am doing the same query (`something in my database has status`) 3 times but I can't figure out how to rewrite the code. I need group route A not to be accessed if status == 0 and group route B if status != 0. So they are not accessible at the same time.

Any way I can rewrite the code so I don't query the db 3 times on every request?

Answer (score 0):

If $status does not change on a per-request basis, this is a perfect use case for using the cache.

```
$status = Cache::remember('status', $minutes, function () {
    // retrieve $status from database.
    return $status;
});
```

If $status is only valid for that request but doesn't change throughout that request, you could store the status in the app container for the duration of the request:

```
App::singleton('currentStatus', function(){
    // retrieve $status from database.
    return $status;
});
```

Then use `app('currentStatus')` in your middlewares.